# Create excel with multiple worksheet using azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Hi I have 5 different set of queries which i want to run in the logic app periodically. It will be better if i create only one excel and add the query result as 5 different worksheet with different name in the logic app for easy access of data.

Is there any possibility to do that.Any link for the above scenario is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new worksheet, you can use "Create Worksheet". To add the data will require to create a table first

[image]

you may need to count the rows and columns for the dataset you want to save and translate into a "table range"

Good example here: https://devblog.pekspro.com/posts/creating-excel-files-in-logic-apps

Comment: Thanks for the link I have created the table and worksheet by following the example. But having issue while trying to insert it Raise the question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74108401/logic-app-a-value-must-be-provided-for-the-item-while-inserting-into-excel-tab