# Logic App - A value must be provided for the item while inserting into Excel Table

Tags: excel, azure-logic-apps

I want a sql resultset to be inserted into Excel table.

As of now in Logic App done following things.

- Created Worksheet
- Created Table
- Executed the sql query
- Created a foreach task and one by one getting the result json and inserting into the Worksheet table i have created above.

From the above task -

- I can see the excel file in the location
- The table is created which i verified
- The sql query executed successfully
- The for each got data to insert

So my logic app looks like:

[image]

- **The Problem is the insert into Row tasks fail while inserting row into the table**

[image]

I don't have a row parameter eventhough its a row task
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your logic app action is called **Add a row into a table** but you didn't provide it with a **row** parameter filled with data, so the value is empty, hence it fails.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonline/#add-a-row-into-a-table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonline/?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556#add-a-row-into-a-table)

[image]